# Absolutely Continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In one of the notes about Analysis , I saw the author used the fact that "Since $f$ is absolutely continuous functions in $[a,b]$ then there exist $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ , I am not sure how he conclude to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is continuous on a compact set.

Comment: That is right, and will help.